# How to get tracking info in observer Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipment-tracking

I am trying to get tracking number and courier name while submitting a shipment in backend but I am not getting these data in observer. below is the code.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
 <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
    <observer name="trackShiping" instance="Aftership\Track\Observer\Tracking"/>
 </event>
 </config>
```

**Tracking.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Aftership\Track\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

 class Tracking implements ObserverInterface {

  protected $logger;

  public function __construct( \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 */
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $magento_order = $observer->getShipment()->getOrder();
    $data = $magento_order->getData();
    $this->logger->info('Data', $data);
  } 
 }
```

In system.log I am not getting data related to tracking. What I am doing wrong. Please help me to get tracking data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I found the answer I need to use **sales_order_shipment_track_save_after** instead of **sales_order_shipment_save_after**.

After that in **`observer`** we can get track data using `$observer->getEvent()->getTrack()`

hope it'll help someone

Comment: you are using which version of magento?

Comment: I guess it was 2.1.7

Comment: This worked well for me on Magento 2.4.1.